# Getting minimum value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to write a code in dplyr where i can take minimum value of two 
consecutive rows

```
A <- data.frame(
  y = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
A
#   y value
# 1 A     1
# 2 B     2
# 3 C     3
# 4 D     4
# 5 E     5
# 6 F     6
```

Desired output

```
y value    
A 1    
C 3    
E 5
```

I want to use dplyr package

General code i use for grouping by name was

```
z <- x %>%    
  group_by(name)%>%
  filter(value == min(value))
```

I cant think of "how to code "consecutive rows" in R or dplyr

Comment: Format your code as code either by highlighting it and clicking the "code format" button in the editor (`{}`) or by indenting it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create an appropriate grouping variable:

```
A %>% mutate(grp = rep(0:(n() - 1) %/% 2 ) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  slice(which.min(x))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   grp [3]
#   y         x   grp
#   <fct> <dbl> <int>
# 1 A         1     1
# 2 C         3     2
# 3 E         5     3
```

Comment: giving an error on original data can you please explain the code so i can use

Comment: Or another option is `A %>% group_by(y = replace(y, c(FALSE, TRUE), y[c(TRUE, FALSE)])) %>% summarise(value = min(value))`

Comment: Run it on your sample data one line at a time to help understand. First, we create a new column called `grp` that is a grouping column for consecutive rows. Then we group by that column. Then, within each group, we `slice` the row corresponding to the minimum x value. If you need more help, please edit your question to *at least* include the error message you get. Preferably enough sample data to reproduce the error.

Comment: i dont understand ceiling part .This error i am getting Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

Comment: the code worked fine till A %>% mutate(grp = rep(1:ceiling(n() / 2), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%   but when i try to slice it give error

Comment: Sounds like the `x` column in your real data is a `list`, and you need it to be just a number. You can try `tidyr::unnest(your_data)`, but if that doesn't work you might want to ask a separate question where you post `dput(head(your_data))` and ask how to convert the `x` column.

Comment: if i do B <- x %>% mutate(grp = rep(1:ceiling(n() / 2), each = 2)) %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(value==min(value)) it gives what i want can i do that

Comment: The `grp` definition is just a way to create the values `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... n / 2, n / 2` where `n` is the number of rows of your data. `ceiling` was rounding up in case you had an odd number of rows. But the `rep` still created an even number of values, so I just replaced it with a better way using the integer division operator `%/%`. Play with it if you want to understand, e.g., `0:10 %/% 2; 0:10 %/% 3; 0:10 %/% 4;`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
A %>%
 group_by(grp = gl(length(value)/2, 2)) %>%
 filter(value == min(value))

  y     value grp  
  <fct> <dbl> <fct>
1 A        1. 1    
2 C        3. 2    
3 E        5. 3
```

It creates a grouping variable using `gl()`, groups by it, and then keeps the minimum value.

Or using the same logic, but creating the groups by `row_number()`:

```
A %>%
 group_by(grp = (row_number()-1) %/% 2) %>%
 filter(value == min(value))
```

Or using `top_n()` instead of `filter()`:

```
A %>%
 group_by(grp = gl(length(value)/2, 2)) %>%
 top_n(-1, wt = value)
```

Or:

```
A %>%
 group_by(grp = (row_number()-1) %/% 2) %>%
 top_n(-1, wt = value)
```

Comment: Nice variety! I think you need something like `gl(ceiling(n() / 2), 2, length = n())` for the `gl` to work with an odd number of rows.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out the subtle differences: `filter(value == min(value))` will keep *all* rows with the min value if there are ties. `top_n` is like `slice` in that it will always be 1 row per group.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for your remarks. Yes, for an odd number, something like you proposed could be used.